# Mallocing a two dimensional array, crashing after trying to print strings

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc

I want a dynamic array of strings, so pointers to pointers of an array.
This is my code(my program crashes after the print) :

```
typedef struct person{
    char *name;
    char **children;
    struct person *nextPerson;

}Person;

int main( ){
    int kidsNum = 1;
    int i;
    Person *first = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    first->name = "George";
    first->children = malloc(kidsNum * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < kidsNum; i++){
        //every string consists maximum of 80 characters
        (first->children)[i] = malloc((80+1) * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s",((first->children)[i]));
        printf("%s",(*((first->children))[i]));
    }
}
```

It crashes after the printf, I don't know if it crashes because bad mallocing, or I don't know how to print the strings correctly in the scenario.

Comment: arguments of scanf & printf shall be the same to print char arrays/

Comment: `printf("%s",(*((first->children))[i]));` --> `printf("%s\n", first->children[i]);`

Comment: compile with all warnings enabled

Answer (score 1):

When you dereference a pointer (which is what `((first->children)[i])` is) you get the value of the memory where the pointer is pointing.

In your case `(*((first->children))[i])` is a *single character* (i.e. a `char`) and not a string. Trying to print it as a string will lead to *undefined behavior* and a probable crash.

Don't dereference the pointer:

```
printf("%s",first->children[i]);
```